# In vim, how to get * to highlight and yank words including special chars (@):,^

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting

In vim 8.0, for **.sh** files, I want to press `*` to highlight the word under the cursor, copy the word into the yank buffer, and I want words to include the characters:

```
( @ ) : , ^
```

in addition to the alphanumeric and underscore characters. I also want a second press of the `*` to clear the highlighting. I note that the default for `iskeyword` is:

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

Here's what I have in my `~/.vimrc` file:

```
function! Highlighting()
   if g:highlighting == 1 && @/ =~ '^\\<'.expand('<cword>').'\\>$'
      let g:highlighting = 0
      return ":silent nohlsearch\<CR>"
   endif

   let @/ = '\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'
   let g:highlighting = 1
   return ":silent set hlsearch\<CR>yiw"
endfunction

set iskeyword+=(,@,),:,,,^

let g:highlighting = 0

nnoremap <silent> <expr> <CR> Highlighting()
```

It works for the most part. What's not working is that words are not including the characters:

```
( @
```

but they are including the others, including the closing parenthesis. Here are some words that should get matched:

```
(@)_name
(@):name
(@)_name_name
(@):name^name
(@):name,name
```

Can anyone suggest a fix that allows this to work with words including all of the characters I want in a word?  Please feel free to suggest a completely different implementation or plugins that solves my needs.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to do the following in the `~/.gvimrc` file:

```
set iskeyword+=(,@-@,),:,,,^
```

To get more information on why the idiom `@-@` is needed, do in vim:

```
:help isfname
```

Comment: I found the answer by looking at help in vim. I'm providing this answer in case it helps other people.